# Дергание картинки в галереи при листании

Tags: android, gallery

**UPD** Сформулировал заново вопрос.

Есть галерея. Для LANDSCAPE-ориентации в адаптере подгружается две картинки и для каждой еще делается inSampleSize = 2, так как картинки не маленькие. При скроллинге происходит дергание галереи, ну понятно почему, из-за подгрузки этих самых картинок. Как можно убрать это дергание? Картинки берутся пока что из assets, но в будущем скорее всего будут браться с сервера.

Единственный выход, как я думаю, - это вынести подгрузку картинок в ImageView в отдельный асинктаск, но хочется узнать наиболее верный и проверенный способ в плане архитектуры кода. Нужно передавать ссылку на ImageView в таск, потом эту ссылку обновлять и т.д.

Кто сталкивался с похожей проблемой - отпишите свое решение, желательно с кодом.

Comment: ты бы код показал...

Comment: код чего? галереи андроидовой? все обычно: адаптер, разметка из двух ImageView на экран. Галерея стандартная. Планшет под версией 3.2.

Comment: ну может ты битмап в юай потоке грузишь... без кода не угадаешь сразу.. =)

Comment: это один момент да, который может тормозить, а еще есть "фишка" галереи - вернуться назад если не дофлингнули, отлистать.